# EXEC in Update query

Tags: sql, subquery, exec

I want to select from a table which has two fields

Tag             Tag Query
(Name)          SELECT Name From table_employee where empid=1

and as a result i want a table like

Tag             Tag Result
(Name)          Tom

So i want to execute the query i retrieve from select and store its result in my table instead of query

```
Update  #TempTagQueries
SET     TagQuery    =   CAST(#Temp2.EmailTagQuery AS varchar(MAX))
FROM    #TempTagQueries AS #Temp1 
            INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT EmailTagQuery,EmailTagIdentifier FROM tblEmailTag) AS #Temp2
            ON #Temp1.TagValue  =   #Temp2.EmailTagIdentifier

SELECT * FROM #TempTagQueries
```

Help me if can do it like or if not what is the solution. As i am avoiding cursor to do it.

```
Update  #TempTagQueries
SET     TagQuery    = EXEC( CAST(#Temp2.EmailTagQuery AS varchar(MAX)))
FROM    #TempTagQueries AS #Temp1 
            INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT EmailTagQuery,EmailTagIdentifier FROM tblEmailTag) AS #Temp2
            ON #Temp1.TagValue  =   #Temp2.EmailTagIdentifier

SELECT * FROM #TempTagQueries
```

Comment: You certainly can't call `EXEC` from within a query, or from within a function. I would ask what it is that you need to accomplish that lead you to this point, and whether you can redesign to avoid that need at all. As each block of Dynamic SQL will have to execute independantly of the rest, I doubt that running this in a loop/cursor would make any negative difference any way. You need to call `n` different blocks of SQL, that's not set based logic. Even if you could magically make this possible, the cursor would be unlikely to be the bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what it is that you're trying do do, it's hard to offer a concrete answer.  The short answer is that there is no way to execute batches of dynamic sql stored in a table without using a loop, to itteratively execute each dynamic sql block.

But the closest to your scenario, that I would see as being valid, could be something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE input (
  operator    VARCHAR(1),
  value1      INT,
  value2      INT
)

INSERT INTO input SELECT '+', 2, 3
INSERT INTO input SELECT '*', 2, 3
GO


CREATE FUNCTION operation (@operator VARCHAR(1), value1 INT, value2 INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
            SELECT @value1 * @value2 AS result WHERE @operator = '*'
  UNION ALL SELECT @value1 + @value2 AS result WHERE @operator = '+'
GO


SELECT
  input.operator,
  input.value1,
  input.value2,
  operation.result
FROM
  input
CROSS APPLY
  dbo.operation(input.operator, input.value1, input.value2) AS operation
```

In this way the result of the function is dependant on the parameters stored in another table.  But you need to be able to pre-code the actual logic into your function, and be able to parameterise it to make it generic.

If you truely need to execute unknown dynamic sql, you need a loop and execute each row by agonising row.